# git hook syntax check

Tags: git

Trying to make a php syntax check hook for a git repository. I was happy when I found a code snippet that does exactly this.

But it seems that the snippet script has a flaw. It executes

```
git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD
```

to get a list of files in the index. Now it runs php -l for each file on that list. The flaw is that a file might differ between the working copy and the staging area. If the staging area php has a syntax error, but the working copy version doesnt, no syntax error is found and the committ succeeds which was the thing to prevent.

Is this a nontrivial problem to solve, or is there some way to run php -l on the staging-version of each file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm very happy using this [php syntax validation hook](http://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/develop-olympus/git-tools/hooks/pre-commit). Hope it will fit your needs too.

It uses `git diff-index --cached --full-index`.

Comment: Yes, this does it much better than the hook from the article.

Comment: the hook is pretty good, however it requires slightly modifications so I can use it. I can't get the correct filename and extension due to 'cut' command

Comment: Link is dead now :(

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there is a problem here.

The snippet you mention probably comes from the blog post [Don’t Commit That Error](http://phpadvent.org/2008/dont-commit-that-error-by-travis-swicegood).
And it includes:

> Next, we call `git diff-index` with a few parameters.
>   First, **we add `--cached` to tell Git we only want files that are going to be committed**.
>   Then, we add `--name-only` to tell Git to only output the name of the files that are being committed.

It seems the files which are about to be committed are precisely the ones a pre-commit hook would want to inspect.
Even if they differ from the files in the working directory, it is their version (in the index) which is to be committed. And it is that same version which will be send to the `php -l` process.

---

Actually, the problem is not in the `git diff-index` itself (with or without `--full-index`) is in the way you will read the file content *in the index*

- The ["PHP Advent 2008" hook](http://phpadvent.org/2008/dont-commit-that-error-by-travis-swicegood) will simply try to access the file from its name (with the risk of accessing the working copy)

```
exec("php -l " . escapeshellarg($file), $lint_output, $return);
```

- The ["phpbb3" hook](http://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/develop-olympus/git-tools/hooks/pre-commit) (mentioned by [takeshkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234780/takeshin) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719883/git-hook-syntax-check/3720692#3720692)) will ask Git for the actual content:

```
result=$(git cat-file -p $sha | /usr/bin/env $PHP_BIN -l 2>/dev/null)
```

Using **[`git cat-file`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cat-file.html)** is the key here, to access an object in the Git repo (i.e. not in the "working directory")

Comment: Yes, that's the code I'm talking about. In $output you get the list of files that are to be committed, correct. But I think you are wrong with your last sentence. It is the working copy version that is sent to php -l, not the staging area version. And that's an error. The hook linked by takeshin seems to do better.

Comment: @zedoo: I have update my answer to reflect on the actual issue here (which is not `git diff-index`)

Answer (score 0):

Cause **pre-commit** hook is not good for working in a team you should use **pre-receive** hook installed on server side to refuse all commits with invalid php syntax and incorrect coding standard.

I've created **pre-receive** python script for that pupose:

```
# A server-side git hook script for checking PHP syntax and validating coding standard
# Depends on: PHP_CodeSniffer (http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/)
# Install: copy this script to <server side repo location>/hooks/pre-receive
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
oldrev, newrev, ref = sys.stdin.read().strip().split(' ')
test_file = os.popen('mktemp').read().strip()
coding_standards = 'PSR2'
for line in os.popen('git diff --name-only %s %s' % (oldrev, newrev)).readlines():
    extension = line.split('.')[-1].strip()
    file_name = line.strip()

    if(extension == 'php'):
        os.system("git cat-file -p %s:%s > %s" % (newrev, file_name, test_file))
        if 0 != os.system('php -l ' + test_file + ' > /dev/null'):
            print "PHP Syntax error in file %s" % (file_name)
            sys.exit(1)

        if 0 != os.system("phpcs -n --standard=%s %s" % (coding_standards, test_file)):
            print "Coding standards fail in file %s" % (file_name)
            sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: The link is broken :-(